# imagestring - Get the size of the string lengh in pixels

Tags: php, image, canvas, png, pixel

*Hello,
Just want to mention in advance that this is not a duplicate.
I already saw similar posts but all of those use a particular font which is not that case.
I'm using default font number 3 (for this example) and I want to be able to calculate the output size and put it in the exact center of my $canvas*

```
imagestring($canvas,3,imagesx($canvas),imagesy($canvas),$myString,imagecolorallocate($canvas,239,13,177));
```

*I know how to make the calculation to put it on center it's pretty easy the only parameter missed is the exact size in pixels (x/y) of my string considering font number 3.
pixels (x/y) of my string considering font number 3.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated answer without using a particular font. PHP embedded fonts are indeed monospaced (Tested and working):

```
$font           = 3;
$img            = imagecreatetruecolor(500, 500);
$text           = "Waldson Patricio";
$color          = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
$size           = strlen($text);

$tw             = $size * imagefontwidth($font);
$th             = imagefontheight($font);



imagestring($img, $font, (imagesx($img) - $tw) / 2 , (imagesy($img) - $th) / 2, $text, $color);
header('Content-type:image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($img);
```

Comment: PERFECT MAN! MANY THANKS! (you still have a small bug on that code but I fixed it :)

Answer (score 3):

[imagettfbbox](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) and [imagettftext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) will do the job:

```
//setup
$font     = '<path to font>';
$string   = 'My String';
$fontSize = 12;

//getting width and height
$bBox   = imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $font, $string);
$width  = $bBox[2] - $bBox[0];
$height = $bBox[1] - $bBox[7];

//drawing in the center
imagettftext($canvas, $fontSize, 0, (imagesx($canvas) - $width)/2, (imagesy($canvas) - $height)/2, $color, $font, $string);
```

Comment: I did... Wasn't very helpful

Comment: If you subtract lower left X from lower right X, you'll get the string width. If you subtract upper left Y from lower left Y, you'll get the height.

Comment: I already saw that but @Walsdon assumes that I use a particular font which is not the case here...

Comment: Well, I didn't plan to use a particular font but since it's WORKING (except you have a bug and need to change $text to $string ;)... I will use this example ! THANKS MAN !

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I cannot find that the fonts used in imagestring have a standard width or spacing. On my PHP implementation, it seems that font 3 has 6 by 9 pixel characters with 1 pixel spacing, monospaced, so 7 * strlen should give a pretty accurate width and 9 should give the height (I assume you're only working with centering one line) of the string image. However, this may be platform or implementation specific, so if it doesn't work for you you'll have to measure yourself.

This solution is if you must use imagestring(), of course -- using imagettftext() and imagettfbbox() would be much better for accurate measuring, as Waldson suggested.